# Android app's release apk has a very big dex file

Tags: android

I have just created my first android app. Its just a single screen app which uses google sign-in and glide animation library. The size of the release apk is `6.2 MB` and `5.7 MB` of it has been taken by `classes.dex` file alone. I really don't want my apk to be that big in size. Please suggest me how can I reduce the overall size of my apk and/or classes.dex file.

I have removed unused libraries from gradle file and it now looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.name.app.name"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile files('libs/helloworld-v1-1.22.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The apk size is sill `6.2 MB`.

---

### EDIT

The size has come down to 4.4 MB after I modified this line of `gradle` script:

```
minifyEnabled false
```

to

```
minifyEnabled true
```

Comment: Remove unused libraries from the build

Comment: `minifyEnabled false` change to `minifyEnabled true`

Comment: I did it and have updated the code in the question above. The size has come down to 4.4 MB now. How can I reduce it down further?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html